# Facing a Problem While Installing Acumos using One click Deploy method(Kubernetes)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, acumos

I have Followed below process for installing Acumos in an Ubuntu 18 Server.

> Open a shell session (bash recommended) on the host on which (for single AIO deployment) or from which (for peer-test deployment) you want to install Acumos, and clone the system-integration repo:

**> git clone https://gerrit.acumos.org/r/system-integration**

> If you are deploying a single AIO instance, run the following command, selecting docker or kubernetes as the target environment. Further instructions for running the script are included at the top of the script.

**> bash oneclick_deploy.sh**

I have done it using k8s as below

**> bash oneclick_deploy.sh k8s**

Everything was running smoothly but at the end i am facing the below issue .

*as docker API is not ready*

[image: Error Screenshot]

Can anyone help me on this Please?

**Note**: I have checked in the kubernetes console everything is fine . A service file is created and also namespace is also created sucessfully in the name of acumos .

Comment: The on-boarding feature builds docker images so needs access to a Docker engine. Can you please post text showing the running containers to show if that one is up? Did you check its logs?  I'll also ask the AIO maintainer to respond here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of that toolset. I'll be happy to help you thru this. Note that it's actively being developed, and will be evolving a lot. But there are some easy things you can do to provide more details so I can debug your situation.

First, start with a clean env:

- $ bash clean.sh

Then reattempt the deployment, piping the console log to a file:

- $ bash oneclick_deploy.sh k8s 2>&1 | tee deploy.log

Review that file to be sure that there's nothing sensitive in it (e.g. passwords or other private info about the deployment that you don't want to share), and if possible attach it here so I can review it. That will be the quickest way to debug.

Also you can let me know some more about your deployment context:

- Did you ensure the Prerequisites:

  - Ubuntu Xenial (16.04), Bionic (18.04), or Centos 7 hosts
  - All hostnames specified in acumos-env.sh must be DNS-resolvable on all hosts (entries in /etc/hosts or in an actual DNS server)
- Did you customize acumos-env.sh, or use the default values
- Send the output of

  - $ kubectl get svc -n acumos
  - $ kubectl get pods -n acumos
  - $ kubectl describe pods -n acumos