# Unable to deploy Acumos in local VM using AIO deployment (Deploying as a Privileged (sudo) User)

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, acumos

Following below steps for AIO deployment:

```
$ git clone https://gerrit.acumos.org/r/system-integration
$ if [[ "$(id -nG "$USER" | grep docker)" == "" ]]; then sudo usermod -aG docker $USER; fi
$ bash system-integration/tools/setup_k8s_stack.sh setup
$ bash system-integration/AIO/setup_prereqs.sh k8s acumos $USER generic 2>&1 | tee aio_prep.log
$ cd system-integration/AIO
$ bash oneclick_deploy.sh 2>&1 | tee aio_deploy.log\
```

We are trying to setup Acumos in local using Kubernetes Based AIO Deployment and Deploying as a Privileged (sudo) User , but we are getting following issues :

1. While executing setup_mariadb in oneclick_deploy.sh script , it shows mariadb status is Pending and the script fails after multiple retries. Attached the log below:

```
setup_mariadb.sh check_running:374 (Mon Jun 28 10:57:45 IST 2021) mariadb status is Pending
+ [[ Pending != \R\u\n\n\i\n\g ]]
+ [[ 490 -le 600 ]]
+ t=500
+ sleep 10
+ check_running mariadb acumos-mariadb
+ trap fail ERR
+ local app=mariadb
+ [[ k8s == \d\o\c\k\e\r ]]
+ local namespace=acumos-mariadb
++ kubectl get pods -n acumos-mariadb -l app=mariadb -o json
++ jq -r '.items[0].status.phase'
+ status=Pending
+ log 'mariadb status is Pending'
+ setx=x
+ set +x
```

2. We tried to comment mariadb setup commands in  oneclick_deploy.sh script and it failed at jenkins , we got below error :

```
setup_jenkins.sh replace_env:703 (Wed Jun 23 16:31:15 IST 2021) Set variable values in k8s templates at deploy/values.yaml
+ set +x
Replacing env variables in deploy/values.yaml
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unterminated `s' command
sed: can't read s~<HOST_IP>~172.30.156.55
10.61.62.67~g: No such file or directory
```

Background：Using VM , with configuration as  ubuntu16.04-64bit 32G RAM + 16Core CPU
We are using default  acumos-env.sh.
Please find below pods, deployment and service status:

[Pods and Deployments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2yob.png)
[Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEFqG.png)

```
kubectl describe pods -n acumos
Name:               acumos-nginx-ingress-controller-rk89n
Namespace:          acumos
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               pnpnipradio74/10.61.62.67
Start Time:         Thu, 24 Jun 2021 17:15:40 +0530
Labels:             app=nginx-ingress
                    app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                    component=controller
                    controller-revision-hash=66fcb76db8
                    pod-template-generation=1
                    release=acumos-nginx-ingress
Annotations:        cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.0.169/32
Status:             Running
IP:                 192.168.0.169
Controlled By:      DaemonSet/acumos-nginx-ingress-controller
Containers:
  nginx-ingress-controller:
    Container ID:  docker://0cc8c4cf03dddd62eeac1f83511a8e39b92fbfa721e392a0a94f340c7663406c
    Image:         us.gcr.io/k8s-artifacts-prod/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.34.1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://us.gcr.io/k8s-artifacts-prod/ingress-nginx/controller@sha256:0e072dddd1f7f8fc8909a2ca6f65e76c5f0d2fcfb8be47935ae3457e8bbceb20
    Ports:         80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Host Ports:    80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Args:
      /nginx-ingress-controller
      --default-backend-service=acumos/acumos-nginx-ingress-default-backend
      --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
      --ingress-class=nginx
      --configmap=acumos/acumos-nginx-ingress-controller
      --default-ssl-certificate=acumos/ingress-cert
      --enable-ssl-passthrough
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 24 Jun 2021 17:15:59 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:       acumos-nginx-ingress-controller-rk89n (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:  acumos (v1:metadata.namespace)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from acumos-nginx-ingress-token-dzpjl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  acumos-nginx-ingress-token-dzpjl:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  acumos-nginx-ingress-token-dzpjl
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute
                 node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule
Events:          <none>


Name:               acumos-nginx-ingress-default-backend-68f6cc8df9-z5w45
Namespace:          acumos
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               pnpnipradio74/10.61.62.67
Start Time:         Thu, 24 Jun 2021 17:15:40 +0530
Labels:             app=nginx-ingress
                    app.kubernetes.io/component=default-backend
                    pod-template-hash=68f6cc8df9
                    release=acumos-nginx-ingress
Annotations:        cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.0.170/32
Status:             Running
IP:                 192.168.0.170
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/acumos-nginx-ingress-default-backend-68f6cc8df9
Containers:
  nginx-ingress-default-backend:
    Container ID:   docker://712f0e6a81a7f268340dd1d8aa8423effce18f20bc03b96d8f8103545a22d79b
    Image:          k8s.gcr.io/defaultbackend-amd64:1.5
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/defaultbackend-amd64@sha256:4dc5e07c8ca4e23bddb3153737d7b8c556e5fb2f29c4558b7cd6e6df99c512c7
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 24 Jun 2021 17:16:00 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       http-get http://:8080/healthz delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:8080/healthz delay=0s timeout=5s period=5s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from acumos-nginx-ingress-backend-token-p2hmd (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  acumos-nginx-ingress-backend-token-p2hmd:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  acumos-nginx-ingress-backend-token-p2hmd
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
--
```

It would be great to get any help on this.

Comment: This seems to be a question about deploying some prepackaged software; that's not the sort of question that's on-topic for Stack Overflow.  The [help/on-topic] describes what's allowed here.  If this is a programming-related question, please edit the question to include a [mcve] with the source code and commands required to reproduce the issue (as text and not images; directly in the question and not behind links; the source code and not just its output).

Comment: Facing a Problem While Installing Acumos using the One-click Deploy method(Kubernetes).
For your reference this is a similar question in StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898111/facing-a-problem-while-installing-acumos-using-one-click-deploy-methodkubernete